# On plothover in flot display all corresponding datapoints for all series on selected item

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using the flot jquery graphing library.
Looking at online examples I am able to use plothover to display a tool tip whenever I hover over a paticular point.  However my graph has multiple series.  And I want the tooltip to display data values for all series on the selected x coordinate. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `item.dataIndex` property in your `plothover` handler.

It's the X coordinate of the selected point, and you can use that to get the Y coordinate from the other series.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5QSy8/1/)

Comment: Here's a modified version of this DEMO, which also highlights all nodes on same coordinate:
http://jsfiddle.net/5QSy8/56/